# Custom post rewrite rule not working

Tags: custom-post-types, rewrite-rules

I'm adding a custom post type like so (names have been altered to protect the innocent):

```
add_action('init', 'my_post_types');
function my_post_types() {

  register_post_type('publication',
    array(
      'labels' => array(...),
      'rewrite' => array(
        'slug' => 'publications/%year%',
        'with_front' => true
        ),
      'public' => true,
      'menu_position' => 21,
      'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'author', 'excerpts', 'revisions', 'thumbnail'),
      'show_ui' => true,
    ));
}
```

I would expect with these settings that the URL of a given publication would be:

```
/publications/2012/name-of-publication
```

However, the URLs produced by `get_permalink()` are coming out as:

```
/publication/name-of-publication
```

The desired URL pattern is recognised by WordPress, but simply redirects to the lower URL. This URL does display the desired page.

I've tried the commonly suggested solutions:

- Making sure that `register_post_type` is called on the `init` action, so it isn't created too late.
- Flushing the rewrite rules by visiting the Permalinks settings page. I also tried doing this on every page using `$wp_rewrite->flush_rules()`, but that would be [pointlessly expensive](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/flush_rewrite_rules) in reality.
- Changing the value of `with_front` has no effect. I wouldn't expect it to since the site is at `/`, not in a subfolder.
- Taking out the `%year%` part of the slug has no effect either, so it isn't causing the rewrite rules to fail.
- I don't have the Redirection plugin installed. It's a known troublemaker with URLs.

If necessary, I can intercept WordPress' routing and force it to deliver the right page, and use filters to return the right URL from `get_permalink`, but that seems like the wrong solution. Setting the rewrite rules when I register the post type is the right solution. Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The undesirable answer I alluded to in my question is to intercept WordPress' routing and URL generation. Manipulate the URLs with:

```
add_filter('post_type_link', 'my_post_link', 10, 3);
function my_post_link($permalink, $post, $leavename) {
  if ($post->post_type == 'publication') {
    $year = date('Y', strtotime($post->post_date));
    return site_url("/publications/$year/$post->post_name");
  }
  return $permalink;
}
```

Then intercept the routing:

```
add_action('template_redirect', 'my_template_redirect');
function my_template_redirect() {
  if (preg_match('!^/publications/([0-9]+)/([a-z0-9-]+)/?!i', $uri, $matches)) {
    $year = $matches[1];
    $publication = $matches[2];

    $ps = get_posts(array(
      'post_type' => 'publication',
      'year' => $year,
      'name' => $publication,
      'numberposts' => 1,
      ));
    if (!empty($ps)) {
      global $post;
      $post = array_shift($ps);
      setup_postdata($post);

      global $wp_query;
      $wp_query->is_404 = false;

      include(get_stylesheet_directory().'/single-publication.php');
      exit;
    }
  }
}
```

This works, but it's **ugly and nasty!**. There are other ways of doing it that involve working with WordPress' rewrite table, but those are also less than ideal. I'd like to find a nicer solution if possible.